# setTimeout works incorrectly in timer function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display the online time in a list of user.
When user online, I set the startOnline as CURRENT_TIME equals stopOnline, and stop it (keep the duration) when the user click on the button log out (set the stopOnline as CURRENT_TIME), but the time keeps increasing. It only stop when I reload the page.

this is my timer function:

```
var runTimer=null;
function timer(time1, time2, id){
    var start=new Date(Date.parse(time1,"YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    var stop=new Date(Date.parse(time2,"YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    var time=0, offline=0;
    if(start.getTime()==stop.getTime()){
        stop=new Date();
    } else offline=1;
    time=stop.getTime()-start.getTime();
    var date = new Date(time);
    var hh = date.getUTCHours();
    var mm = date.getUTCMinutes();
    var ss = date.getSeconds();
    if (hh < 10) {hh = "0"+hh;}
    if (mm < 10) {mm = "0"+mm;}
    if (ss < 10) {ss = "0"+ss;}
    var t = hh+":"+mm+":"+ss;
    $('table.user tr[user-id="'+id+'"] .online').html(t);
    if(offline==1) clearTimeout(runTimer);
    runTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        if(offline==0) timer(time1, time2, id);
    },1000);
}
```

and in each loop in an ajax fetching user from database I call the function

```
$.ajax({
    url      : 'getinfo.php',
    type     : 'get',
    async    : false,
    dataType : 'json',
    success  : function (data){
        $.each (data, function (key, item){
            timer(item['startOnline'],item['stopOnline'],item['id']);
        });
    }
});
```

when user click on the log out button, I call the ajax again to update the item['stopOnline'] and expect the timer will keep the duration.

**UPDATE**
I solved my problem by calling ajax get startOnline and stopOnline in the function timer and setInterval the function in the ajax getinfo

Comment: Do you expect the time to be exact to the milliseconds?? That is what your check is doing, that is not going to happen unless you are really lucky. I am also not sure how the time in your code above changes.

Comment: @epascarello no, i just want it to be exact to the seconds.

Comment: How does the timer1/2 change in that code? You pass the same variables which do not get anything subtracted from them. Seems like the time in that code above will jut remain constant. The if check should be `greater than or equal to`

Comment: So why is your ajax still looping if the time reaches zero? Why are you not showing that ajax call?

Comment: You can't rely on timing in computers to be exact. It will **never** be exact 100% of the time.